# How to reliably works with Apache Pluto 1.1.7?

Tags: tomcat, deployment, portlet

The company I am working at is developing a (medium sized) portlet.
We use **Apache Pluto 1.1.7** as the portlet container and **Eclipse Helios Service Release 2**
as IDE, both for Windows XP).

We added the Pluto server to the Eclipse *Servers tab*, using the *Pluto Bundle v1.1* environment and with redeploy on resource
changes.

Now we have some very annoying issues with the deploy process.
Unless we go through **multiple** clean-remove-add steps, Pluto fails to run the portlet with
a *PortletException*.
Also the changes made to the sources are not deployed, **even when we force a deploy** within Eclipse.

Every time before testing a new change, we need to:

- Stop Pluto
- Clean Pluto work dir
- Stop Pluto
- Remove the portlet from Pluto (using Eclipse)
- Clean Pluto work dir again
- Stop Pluto
- Clean the portlet project
- Add the portlet back to Pluto
- Clean Pluto work dir again
- Restart in debug.

If we miss one of this step we either got and exception or the deployed portlet is not up to date.
This is very time consuming and frustrating.

---

**What is happening here? How can we reliably deploy a portlet to Pluto with Eclipse?**

Comment: Pluto 1.1.7 was released on 9 February 2009 - roughly 7 years ago. It might be time to update to a more recent environment. On a quick check on the homepage, I couldn't even find the downloadable archives any more - they're only offering 2.0.3, which is from September 2011

Comment: @OlafKock. Some thoughts here. But we don't have such a privilege, we **must** stick with Pluto 1.1.7.

Comment: well, that's why I only provided it as a comment, not as an answer. It might solve your problem though, but I'm aware that this is not a popular suggestion. Sooner or later you'll have to bite the bullet.